# State of an instance is not updating -- SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

So I have this structure Task which has a @State completion:

```
struct Task:Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    @State var completion:Bool = false
    var priority:String? = nil
    @State var completionDate:Date? = nil
    var creationDate:Date
    var fullDescription:String
}
```

In a TaskItem:View I'm trying to make a checkbox that will update the state properly:

```
struct TaskItem: View {
    
    @State var task:Task
    @State var isChecked:Bool = false
    
    func toggle(){
        isChecked = !isChecked
        task.completion = isChecked
        if isChecked {
            task.completionDate = Date()
        } else {
            task.completionDate = nil
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
       
                    Button(action: toggle){
                        
                       Image(systemName: isChecked ? "square.split.diagonal.2x2": "square")
                        
      
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

But even though isChecked changes and the image as well, the task.completion doesn't. How can I fix this?

I'm currently using this to view it:

```
struct TaskItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let task =  testTask()
        TaskItem(task: task)
    }
}
```

Comment: do not use `@State` outside a `View` like you have in `Task`. They are only to be used inside a View.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem. If you post that in the answers, I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `@State` outside a `View` like you have in `Task`. They are only to be used inside a `View`.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) explaining `@State` is quite useful:

> "... You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it.
> For this reason, declare your state properties as private, to prevent clients of your view from accessing them.
> It is safe to mutate state properties from any thread....".

Note: that Swift also has a `Task` struct, that is a unit of asynchronous work. This may become a problem
if you use the same name for your `Task` struct.

Answer (score 1):

The `@State` property wrapper is NOT meant to be used inside a data model, like your struct Task.  The `@State` property wrapper is a property wrapper meant to be used on SwiftUI Views. If you remove `@State`, you should be in good shape.